# Set textview xamarin not working

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I try to change text from code behind. This is my code

```
TextView txtHome1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtHome);
txtHome1.Text = "Hello";
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Home);
```

When i click button, it move to Home layout, txtHome is on Home layout, and i try to set txtHome = "Hello" but cannnot, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in the wrong order.
Set your content view first, and then edit the text.

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Home);
TextView txtHome1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtHome);
txtHome1.Text = "Hello";
```